# Multiple domains pointing to single Rails app on VPS Hosting (Like Shopify)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, vps

Asking the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360944/multiple-domains-pointing-to-single-heroku-rails-app-via-nameservers-displaying, but I am on VPS hosting instead of Heroku. **I want customers to be able to add domain names dynamically.**

How do I config my VPS(ubuntu 12.04) hosting and rails app to do this? I know you can add multiple domain names to Heroku app, how about VPS?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old railscast, but it will definitely point you to the right direction:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a way to do this with a full domain like www.example.com instead of subdomain? :)